# Not getting connected to the facebook instant articles

Tags: php, facebook, drupal-7, facebook-php-sdk

I am facing problem in connecting to facebook instant articles access.

As strict mode is enabled now, While I am trying to access the url :--

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=189806944926537&state=46077b1075124dfe5bb4ff63000c01cc&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com%2Fadmin%2Fconfig%2Fservices%2Ffb-instant-articles%2Fapi%2Flogin&scope=pages_show_list%2Cpages_manage_instant_articles
```

The request uri is:

```
http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api
```

On facebook app settings page, I have made the settings of Valid OAuth Redirect URIs like this:

```
http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api
```

and

```
http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com also.
```

In the app Domain Field We added:

```
sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com
```

and in the Website url We added

```
http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com
```

But while trying to connect through the url mentioned above it is throwing error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Comment: _“The request uri is :”_ - you mean the redirect_uri? No it isn’t.

Comment: Yes, request uri is redirect_uri.

Comment: Well then specify the right one.

Comment: This is redirect_uri :-- http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api

Comment: Not in your login dialog call.

Comment: CBroe.. Could you throw more light on this ?

Comment: Just go look at the first URL you posted, and figure out what the redirect_uri parameter actually contains ...

Comment: I have added   http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api/login in the valid oauth redirect URI's. Now it is asking for fb password but not to  select the page where the fb instant articles will be published ...... It just coming back to the  page   http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api#_=_

Comment: _“Now it is asking for fb password but not to select the page where the fb instant articles will be published ”_ - and why should it …? You are only performing the login here, so that the user can grant permissions to your app. You have not shown _anything_ here so far that actually had anything to do with IA, code-wise ...

Comment: Iam explaining this :-- On a page which is http://sciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api  .. It asks for APPID and then for the APP Secret of the facebook Page.   On the page  (/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api) , It asks for publicationId to connect site to the facebook Page. (appears in head tag of the page ).

Comment: Then again on the first page (/admin/config/services/fb-instant-articles/api) , a facebook link is being made given below. I click on it and it redirect me to facebook page and ask for password . But it does not ask for facebook page in which I want to publish articles which it used to be.  So, I want help in this case and want to select the facebook page after making the login through the above link.

Comment: The link is :-- https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=189806944926537&state=e45c863b002f3651d6a45f6a99b3b865&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsciencenews.org.400elmp02.blackmesh.com%2Fadmin%2Fconfig%2Fservices%2Ffb-instant-articles%2Fapi%2Flogin&scope=pages_show_list%2Cpages_manage_instant_articles